# number of real roots of this polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

Consider polynomials of this form $$f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}C_ix^i - x^n$$ Here, all $C_i\ge0$ and $x\ge0$
How many real roots does it have? Intuitively it seems like it should have exactly 1 real root. Reason: $x^n$ grows faster than the other terms. So once the polynomial crosses zero, the polynomial will continue to be more and more negative. However I am unable to prove it. Plz help.

Comment: How about trying an example. Like $x - x^2$? That being said, have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs

Comment: wow thanks the link is very useful and what I was looking for :)

Comment: So this polynomial can have atmost 1 positive root . I have a follow up question. Can I exploit the structure to solve for the root with a faster algorithm than newtons method? (maybe ternary search).

Comment: I'm not sure what a ternary search would be in this context, but binary searches (that isolate the root to one half or the other of the interval each iteration) gain at most one decimal place per iteration, which presumably would be the same for ternary searches; Newton's method, on the other hand, roughly *doubles* the number of decimal places of accuracy with each iteration.

Comment: I was thinking that $f`(x)$ also has the same structure as $f(x)$ so $f'(x)$ has atmost one positive root, So $f(x)$ can initially increase to have atmost one local maxima before it starts decreasing to cross x axis and becomes forever negative, So was thinking to use ternary search but thanks for the info that Newton's method doubles the digits in each iteration. Definitely better